# php error with $option['label'] ===

Tags: php, magento

I put this code in a view.phtml file to retrieve a list of an attribute's values in all product page with a specific css style for a particular value. But there's php errors that I don't find.

Can someone help to resolve or share anything to do?  Thanks

```
 <?php $attribute_code = "my_attribute_code" ?>
 <?php $attribute_details = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("catalog_product", $attribute_code) ?>
 <?php $options = $attribute_details->getSource()->getAllOptions(false) ?>
      <ul>
        <?php foreach($options as $option): ?>
           <li>
             <?php if ($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);?>) === $option['label']): ?>
                 <p style="font-weight:bold;"><?php echo $option['label']; ?></p>
             <?php else: ?>
                 <p><?php echo $option['label']; ?></p>
             <?php endif; ?>
           </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synax error:

I removed this string: `;?>)` from the first conditional statement and everything looks fine.

```
<?php if ($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) === $option['label']): ?>
```